# Adding fixed size array to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, arrays, enumerable

**This method gets:**

`IEnumerable<object[]>` - in which every array is in **fixed size** (it represent relational 
data structure).

`DataEnumerable.Column[]` - some metadata columns,mostly they will have the same value for all rows.

**Expected outcome:**

each "row" should get value for each of these columns (so the data structure remains relational).

```
    private IEnumerable<object[]> BindExtraColumns(IEnumerable<object[]> baseData, int dataSize, DataEnumerable.Column[] columnsToAdd)
    {
        int extraColumnsLength = columnsToAdd.Length;
        object[] row = new object[dataSize + extraColumnsLength];

        string columnName;
        int rowNumberColumnIndex = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < extraColumnsLength; i++)
        {
            //Assign values that doesn't change between lines..
            // Assign rowNumberColumnIndex if row number column exists
        }

        //Assign values that change here, since we currently support only row number
        // i'ts not generic enough        
        if (rowNumberColumnIndex != -1)
        {
            int rowNumber = 1;

            foreach (var baseRow in baseData)
            {
                row[rowNumberColumnIndex] = rowNumber;

                Array.Copy(baseRow, 0, row, extraColumnsLength, dataSize);

                yield return row;

                rowNumber++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var baseRow in baseData)
            {
                Array.Copy(baseRow, 0, row, extraColumnsLength, dataSize);

                yield return row;
            }
        }
    }
```

this method can be called from hundreds of threads with relatively big data sets so
performance here is critical, and i tried to create as minimum new objects as possible.

Please note - this is a private method, which used **ONLY BY** DataReader, which read each line, and passes it to another array immediately **prior to reading the next line**.

So - does copying arrays here be optimized here somehow, and should i use (carefully) memory to boost things here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fundamentally broken. You're just returning a reference to the same array every time, which means that unless the caller uses the data within each item *immediately*, it effectively gets lost. For example, suppose I use:

```
List<object[]> rows = BindExtraColumns(data, size, toAdd).ToList();
```

Then when I iterate over the rows, I find the same data in every row. That's really not a good experience.

I think it would make *much* more sense to create a new array for each iteration. Yes, that's a lot of extra memory being used - but it doesn't surprise callers nearly as much.

If you really don't want to do that, I suggest you change the approach so that the caller has to pass in an `Action<object[]>` to be executed on each row, with the documented proviso that if the caller stashes a reference to the array, they may well be surprised by the results.

You're obviously very concerned about performance, but if your data is coming from a database I'd expect the array creation/copying performance to be insignificant. You should write the *simplest* (and most reliable) code that works first, and then benchmark it to see whether it performs well enough. Unless you've got *evidence* that you need to make this surprising design choice, it feels like you're optimizing way too early.

EDIT: Now we know that it's a private method *only* used in one specific place, I would *still* avoid this reuse. It's simply fragile. I really would change to passing in an `Action<object[]>` or simply copying the data to a new array every time. I certainly wouldn't keep the current approach without *strong evidence* that it's a bottleneck: as I said before, I'd expect the database communication to be much more important. Leaving timebombs in your code like this very rarely works out well.

If you *really, really* want to keep doing this, you should document it *very* strongly, giving severe warnings that the result is non-idiomatic.

In terms of whether there's *more* optimization you could do - well... one alternative would be to avoid having to work with a single array in the first place. You could create a class which held references to *both* arrays (the current base row and the fixed data) and exposed an indexer which returned the value from one array or the other based on which index was being requested. We don't know what you're doing with the data ("passes it to another array" doesn't really mean anything) so we don't know whether that's feasible, but it would be efficient *and* could be implemented without the odd behaviour.

Comment: I had that concern, and i wrote it like you said to begin with. But how can i know/handle the memory limitation? And BTW - it currently works fine!

Comment: @Yosi: Presumably it currently works fine because of how you *happen* to use it. That doesn't mean it's not overly fragile. As for "the memory limitation" - *what* memory limitation? You haven't explained exactly what that limitation is, or how you've diagnosed it.

Comment: first, thanks for your help! I think i got your point. It seems frightening to me to create so many arrays for each invocation, but i guess it might not be a problem, and for sure regardless of that this code looks bad after what you described..

Comment: @Yosi: Any reason for unaccepting this? Does it not work somehow? If so, please give more details.

Comment: @Yosi: See my edit. It's still not at all clear that you've actually got any evidence that the performance is critical here - you certainly haven't *posted* any evidence to that effect (backed up by measuring the impact of copying the array data vs the impact of reading the data to start with).

Comment: Side note - this wan't my first option for implementing what I needed.  A more favorite solution by me was to [add columns to datareader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504061/how-to-add-columns-to-datareader) (the `IEnumerable` in this question was created by this DataReader)